# Applied aggFunc with cellrender and aggFunc is not showing in parent row

Tags: angular, ag-grid, aggregation, ag-grid-angular, cellrenderer

Used aggFunc "first" with cellRenderer for the column, the first cell in children row didn't show up in the parent, but when you hover over the parent cell and do copy on the empty parent cell, then paste in on a notepad, the value of the first child cell is there. How can I make it display in the parent cell?
[final result after applying aggFunc:'first', how to make it show up like column id does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlyn7.png)

I tried adding

and  around my aggFunc result but didn't work

```js
ag-grid.ts

columns.push({
      headerName: element.DisplayName,
      field: element.field,
      rowGroup: false,
      aggFunc: this.firstTitle,
      cellRender: (params) => { return params.data.title } // params.data.title: <a href="....com"> title </a>
})

// use builtin 'first' should work here too
public firstTitle(params:Array<any>){
       let title = params[0].match(new regexp('<a. ?*>(.*?)</a>');
       return title;
}
```

I expected the first title in child row show up in parent but none were displayed

Answer (score 0):

There is no such field as cellRender in ColDef. You should define cellRenderer instead.
Refer to this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/E45iZRlGKhZy91icE3yK?p=info) for an example (there is a custom first-like aggFunc applied against Year column.
Most likely your code should be as following:

```
columns.push({
      headerName: element.DisplayName,
      field: element.field,
      rowGroup: false,
      aggFunc: this.firstTitle,
      cellRenderer: (params) => { return params.value }
})
```